# How to pase django urlname to a javascript in the template

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates

I am trying to use  `url:"{% url 'final-result' %}",` in my template so that my javascript can use that in an ajax call.

I got `Reverse for 'final_result' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Here is my ajax:

```
$(".score_statics").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    $.ajax({
        url:"{% url 'final-result' %}",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'name':name
        },
        success: function(dataArr){

        },
    });
```

And this is my url pattern

```
url(r'^score/result/$', views.final_result, name='final-result'),
```

And my views.py

```
def final_result(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
    ...

    return JsonResponse({ "PASS"})
```

Do I have anything unset or uninstalled ?

Comment: where is your ajax? in your template or a separate js file?

Comment: Are you using namespaced urls? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: @PatrickBeeson Yes.You are right .Thank you so much!! you solve my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely using namespaced urls: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces.

Try finding the namespace, then adjusting your template tag to `{% url "namespace:final-result" %}`